# Using DOMdocument createElement in foreach

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I want to generate content with an array and place that in my Document that I loaded over a site. That is what I got so far. Is there a way for this with the foreach? Is there an append function?

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
            $dom->loadHTML($data);

            // create the new element
            $newNode = $dom->createElement('div', 'this is new');
            $newNode->setAttribute('id', 'new_div');

            //foreach

            $count = 0;
            foreach($tags->contents as $content){
                $contents[$count] = $content->text;
            }

            // fetch and replace the old element
            $oldNode = $dom->getElementById('blog-xpath');
            $oldNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $oldNode);


            $nodes = $dom->saveHTML($dom->documentElement);
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data you have in your array and the HTML you want to create for that sample data?

Comment: I think I got it -> 

foreach($tags->contents as $content){
                $node = $dom->createElement('div',$content->text);
                $newNode->appendChild($node);
            }